# Unregistering a broadcast receiver to MEDIA_BUTTON

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a service that I've registered a MediaButtonEventReceiver within it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE))
            .registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
                    getPackageName(), MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class
                            .getName()));

}
```

It works fine. And in `onDestroy` method I'm trying to unregister this receiver.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE))
            .unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
                    getPackageName(), MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class
                            .getName()));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And in main activity I stop this service. But it doesn't work. My `MediaIntentReceiver` class still receives `MEDIA_BUTTON` actions an does it's works and other programs can't. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you certain that your service stops?, have you verified that the onDestroy method is called?

Comment: Yes it stops. And onDestroy method also gets called but it doesn't unregister the broadcast listener.